# How to Import/Export simple and Configurable Product in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to Import/Export simple and Configurable Product in magento 1.9.2? 
I need to import Configurable product and simple product through csv in Magento
but upload but can't joint with Configurable and simple product anyone can help me?

```
sku,_type,_attribute_set,_product_websites,title,price,description,short_description,weight,status,qty,name,visibility,tax_class_id
bssfw011,simple,indianink,base,10,999,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,100,1,55,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,1,0
bssfw012,simple,indianink,base,8,999,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,100,1,55,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,1,0
bssfw013,simple,indianink,base,9,999,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,100,1,55,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,1,0
bssfw014,simple,indianink,base,5,999,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,100,1,56,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,1,0
bssfw015,configurable,indianink,base,0,999,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,100,1,0,BLUE SUIT SETS FOR WOMEN,4,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi create file app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Convert\Adapter\Productwithlinks.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


class Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Productwithlinks
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
{

    /**
     * Save product (import)
     *
     * @param array $importData
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     * @return bool
     */
    public function saveRow(array $importData)
    {
        $product = $this->getProductModel();
        $product->setData(array());
        if ($stockItem = $product->getStockItem()) {
            $stockItem->setData(array());
        }

        if (empty($importData['store'])) {
            if (!is_null($this->getBatchParams('store'))) {
                $store = $this->getStoreById($this->getBatchParams('store'));
            } else {
                $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, required field "%s" not defined', 'store');
                Mage::throwException($message);
            }
        } else {
            $store = $this->getStoreByCode($importData['store']);
        }

        if ($store === false) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, store "%s" field not exists', $importData['store']);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        if (empty($importData['sku'])) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, required field "%s" not defined', 'sku');
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        $product->setStoreId($store->getId());
        $productId = $product->getIdBySku($importData['sku']);
  $new = true; // fix for duplicating attributes error
        if ($productId) {
            $product->load($productId);
   $new = false; // fix for duplicating attributes error
        }
        $productTypes = $this->getProductTypes();
        $productAttributeSets = $this->getProductAttributeSets();

        /**
        * Check product define type
        */
        if (empty($importData['type']) || !isset($productTypes[strtolower($importData['type'])])) {
            $value = isset($importData['type']) ? $importData['type'] : '';
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"', $value, 'type');
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        $product->setTypeId($productTypes[strtolower($importData['type'])]);
        /**
        * Check product define attribute set
        */
        if (empty($importData['attribute_set']) || !isset($productAttributeSets[$importData['attribute_set']])) {
            $value = isset($importData['attribute_set']) ? $importData['attribute_set'] : '';
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"', $value, 'attribute_set');
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        $product->setAttributeSetId($productAttributeSets[$importData['attribute_set']]);

        foreach ($this->_requiredFields as $field) {
            $attribute = $this->getAttribute($field);
            if (!isset($importData[$field]) && $attribute && $attribute->getIsRequired()) {
                $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, required field "%s" for new products not defined', $field);
                Mage::throwException($message);
            }
        }

  //================================================
  // this part handles configurable products and links 
  //================================================

  if ($importData['type'] == 'configurable') {
   $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
   $configAttributeCodes = $this->userCSVDataAsArray($importData['config_attributes']);
   $usingAttributeIds = array();
   foreach($configAttributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
    if ($product->getTypeInstance()->canUseAttribute($attribute)) {
     if ($new) { // fix for duplicating attributes error
      $usingAttributeIds[] = $attribute->getAttributeId();
     }
    }
   }
   if (!empty($usingAttributeIds)) {
    $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($usingAttributeIds);
    $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray());
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
   }
   if (isset($importData['associated'])) {
    $product->setConfigurableProductsData($this->skusToIds($importData['associated'], $product));
   }
  }

        /**
         * Init product links data (related, upsell, crosssell, grouped)
         */
    if (isset($importData['related'])) {
      $linkIds = $this->skusToIds($importData['related'], $product);
      if (!empty($linkIds)) {
        $product->setRelatedLinkData($linkIds);
      }
    }
    if (isset($importData['upsell'])) {
      $linkIds = $this->skusToIds($importData['upsell'], $product);
      if (!empty($linkIds)) {
        $product->setUpSellLinkData($linkIds);
      }
    }
    if (isset($importData['crosssell'])) {
      $linkIds = $this->skusToIds($importData['crosssell'], $product);
      if (!empty($linkIds)) {
        $product->setCrossSellLinkData($linkIds);
      }
    }
    if (isset($importData['grouped'])) {
      $linkIds = $this->skusToIds($importData['grouped'], $product);
      if (!empty($linkIds)) {
        $product->setGroupedLinkData($linkIds);
      }
    }

  //================================================





        if (isset($importData['category_ids'])) {
            $product->setCategoryIds($importData['category_ids']);
        }

        foreach ($this->_ignoreFields as $field) {
            if (isset($importData[$field])) {
                unset($importData[$field]);
            }
        }

        if ($store->getId() != 0) {
            $websiteIds = $product->getWebsiteIds();
            if (!is_array($websiteIds)) {
                $websiteIds = array();
            }
            if (!in_array($store->getWebsiteId(), $websiteIds)) {
                $websiteIds[] = $store->getWebsiteId();
            }
            $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
        }

        if (isset($importData['websites'])) {
            $websiteIds = $product->getWebsiteIds();
            if (!is_array($websiteIds)) {
                $websiteIds = array();
            }
            $websiteCodes = split(',', $importData['websites']);
            foreach ($websiteCodes as $websiteCode) {
                try {
                    $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite(trim($websiteCode));
                    if (!in_array($website->getId(), $websiteIds)) {
                        $websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {}
            }
            $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
            unset($websiteIds);
        }

        foreach ($importData as $field => $value) {
            if (in_array($field, $this->_inventorySimpleFields)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (in_array($field, $this->_imageFields)) {
                continue;
            }

            $attribute = $this->getAttribute($field);
            if (!$attribute) {
                continue;
            }

            $isArray = false;
            $setValue = $value;

            if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
                $value = split(self::MULTI_DELIMITER, $value);
                $isArray = true;
                $setValue = array();
            }

            if ($value && $attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
                $setValue = $this->getNumber($value);
            }

            if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
                $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

                if ($isArray) {
                    foreach ($options as $item) {
                        if (in_array($item['label'], $value)) {
                            $setValue[] = $item['value'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $setValue = null;
                    foreach ($options as $item) {
                        if ($item['label'] == $value) {
                            $setValue = $item['value'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $product->setData($field, $setValue);
        }

        if (!$product->getVisibility()) {
            $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
        }

        $stockData = array();
        $inventoryFields = $product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ? $this->_inventorySimpleFields : $this->_inventoryOtherFields;
        foreach ($inventoryFields as $field) {
            if (isset($importData[$field])) {
                if (in_array($field, $this->_toNumber)) {
                    $stockData[$field] = $this->getNumber($importData[$field]);
                }
                else {
                    $stockData[$field] = $importData[$field];
                }
            }
        }
        $product->setStockData($stockData);

        $imageData = array();
        foreach ($this->_imageFields as $field) {
            if (!empty($importData[$field]) && $importData[$field] != 'no_selection') {
                if (!isset($imageData[$importData[$field]])) {
                    $imageData[$importData[$field]] = array();
                }
                $imageData[$importData[$field]][] = $field;
            }
        }

        foreach ($imageData as $file => $fields) {
            try {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . $file, $fields);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {}
        }

        $product->setIsMassupdate(true);
        $product->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);

        $product->save();

        return true;
    }




    protected function userCSVDataAsArray($data) {
  return explode(',', str_replace(" ", "", $data));
 }

 protected function skusToIds($userData,$product) {
  $productIds = array();
  foreach ($this->userCSVDataAsArray($userData) as $oneSku) {
   if (($a_sku = (int)$product->getIdBySku($oneSku)) > 0) {
    parse_str("position=", $productIds[$a_sku]);
   }
  }
  return $productIds;
 }


}
```

and Go->admin->system->import/export->Dataflow - Advanced Profiles->Add New Template->Profile Name ->ImportConfigurableProduct
and Actions XML ->Paste Code

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[import_product.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_productwithlinks</var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

Then goto->Var create ->import directory -> put file import_product.csv

CSV Method is

websites,attribute_set,type,category_ids,sku,has_options,name,meta_title,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,url_key,url_path,config_attributes,custom_design,page_layout,options_container,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,gift_message_available,size_guide_image,design,color_linked_product,price,special_price,msrp,status,visibility,tax_class_id,size,sleeve,short_description,description,size_guide,size_fit,material_care,meta_keyword,custom_layout_update,special_from_date,special_to_date,news_from_date,news_to_date,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,inventory_qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,low_stock_date,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,stock_status_changed_automatically,use_config_enable_qty_increments,product_name,store_id,product_type_id,product_status_changed,product_changed_websites,gallery,related,upsell,crosssell,tier_prices,associated,bundle_options,grouped,group_price_price,downloadable_options,downloadable_sample_options,super_attribute_pricing,product_tags,weight,color,is_recurring

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way you can do it via Magento admin panel.

**Step 1) Click on System –> Import/Export–>Dataflow-Profiles and you will see this**

[image]

**Step 2) Now After Click on Dataflow-Profiles you will see this**

[image]

**Step 3) Now Click on Add New Profile & it will take you on a new window**
[image]

**Step 4) Now fill all the details in the Columns which i fill below image.**
[image]

**Step 5) Now After Filling all the details click on Save and Continue Edit button**
[image]

Step 6) Now if you want to Export Product just click on **Run Profile in Popup button**.It will take a time to download your file so just relax for a 5 minute.

**Step 7 ) After All If you want to Import your Product just Follow Above step only change the Import option which i show you in a image**

[image]